# How to set the li value (text inside the li) in the input filed in TODO application when user click on update button?

Tags: javascript, dom

Below is my code actually I wanted to set the li text into the input field when a user click on update button . The code is working input element is shown when user click on update button but the value which is in the li tag is not shown in the input filed but it is shown in the console I also attached the picture to clear this  when I replace the input with a button

```
 [function addTodo() {
      // create li
      var todo_input = document.getElementById('todo-input');
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var textNode = document.createTextNode(todo_input.value);
      li.setAttribute('class', 'li');
      li.appendChild(textNode);
    
      // create update button
      var updateBtn = document.createElement('button');
      var updateText = document.createTextNode('UPDATE');
    
    li.appendChild(updateBtn);
      li.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    
      addList.appendChild(li);
    
    
    }
    
    
    function updateItem(e) {
    
      var val1 = e.parentNode.firstChild;
    
      var inputVal = document.createElement('input');
      inputVal.setAttribute('class','todo-input');
      inputVal.setAttribute('type','text');
    
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(val1.nodeValue);
    inputVal.appendChild(textNode);
    }][1]
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add an event listener for the buttons.

Comment: This is not the issue code is working fine in the console but it's not showing li text value in the input field in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't append the text in the input box. Use the value attribute.

```js
inputVal.value = val1.nodeValue;
```